# Add a xml layout multiple into another xml with scrollview

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm new to the android world. I have a xml layout that i want to add as child to other xml file's scrollview.

This is the layout[ offerview.xml ] to be inserted multiple times is -

[image]

The xml[activity_offer.xml] into which it has to be inserted is -

[image]

Java Code of the activity is -

```
public class OfferActivity extends Activity {

private static final String name = "Reebok";
private static final String content = "50% off on Reebok Shoes at Reliance Mart";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_offer);

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.offerview, null);

    TextView offerItemTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.offerItemTextView);
    offerItemTextView.setText(name);

    TextView offerContentTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.offertextView);
    offerContentTextView.setText(content);

    ImageView offerImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.offerImageView);
    offerImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ps);

    ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.offersLayout)).addView(v);


    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.offer, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

At the moment i was just trying to include view only one time. The app crashed.

[image]

[image]

I've been stuck forever on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `layout_width` and `layout_height` in your `offersLayout`

```
...
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/offersLayout">
</LinearLayout>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Log file say that you must add layout_width atts of LinerLayout in activity_offer.xml.
You can using merge tag to using again xml file